# Meteor ReactiveVar doesnt works with Meteor.call in event

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I am using ReactiveVar. `onCreated` I set ReactiveVar `with Meteor.Call`. When I try to change my reactive variables from `event`, I am getting `Exception in delivering result of invoking 'namelist'` Hope my code below will explain my problem more.

Template:

```
   <template name="Name">
    {{#each list}}
      Name : {{name}}
      Age : {{age}}
    {{/each}}
    <button class="loadmore">Load More</button>
    <template>
```

Helper:

```
Template.Name.helpers({
  'list': function(){
    return Template.instance().list.get();
  }
})
```

OnCreated:

```
Template.Name.onCreated(function () {
  this.limit = new ReactiveVar(5);
  this.skip = new ReactiveVar(0);
  this.list = new ReactiveVar();

  Meteor.call("namelist", Template.instance().skip.get(), Template.instance().limit.get(), function(error, result) {
    if(error){
      alert("Oops!!! Something went wrong!");
      return;
    } else {
      this.list.set(result);
      this.skip.set(this.limit.get());
      this.limit.set(this.limit.get()+5);
      return;
    }
  }.bind(this));

});
```

Event :

```
Template.Name.events({
  'click .loadmore': function(event, template) {

    Meteor.call("namelist", template.skip.get(), template.limit.get(), function(error, result) {
      if(error){
        alert("Oops!!! Something went wrong!");
        return;
      } else {
        temp = template.list.get();
        temp.push(result);
        template.list.set(temp); // Here I am getting error of Exception in delivering result of invoking 'namelist'
        template.skip.set(template.limit.get());
        template.limit.set(template.limit.get()+5);
        return;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Right before you get the error in the event, can you show us what "temp" looks like? console.log() it possibly.

Comment: @TimC. Thanks for your replay. I fixed this issue. the problem is temp variable isn't an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without executing the code I can't tell precisely what's going on, but it may be that your initial `Meteor.call` isn't setting `list` to be an array. Additionally, `temp` is declared without `var` so it's leaking into the global namespace. In your event handler you could try writing this:

```js
var temp = template.list.get() || [];
temp.push(result);
template.list.set(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I fixed the problem. `list` isnt an array and I used `var` to declare temp variable :)